# Node service Active (running) but unavailable

Tags: services, node.js

I have just managed to get my service status active via the help of yourselves, however it still appears that the node service is not actually running.

So put simply, I know my node app is running, but for all intensive purposes, it isn't acting as it should.

## Service status

```
root@server:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl status parsoid.service 
● parsoid.service - MediaWiki Parsoid Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/parsoid.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-12-15 21:18:06 GMT; 29s ago
 Main PID: 18799 (node)
    Tasks: 9
   Memory: 34.8M
      CPU: 1.449s
   CGroup: /system.slice/parsoid.service
           └─18799 /usr/bin/node /var/www/gwart/mediawiki/extensions/VisualEditor/parsoid/bin/server.js

Dec 15 21:18:06 server.live-servers.net systemd[1]: Started MediaWiki Parsoid Server.
Dec 15 21:18:07 server.live-servers.net node[18799]: {"name":"parsoid","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":18799,"level":30,"levelPath":"info/service-runner","msg":"master(18799) initializing 2 workers","time":"2018-12-15T21:18:07.189Z","v":0}
Dec 15 21:18:07 server.live-servers.net node[18799]: {"name":"parsoid","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":18811,"level":60,"moduleName":"lib/index.js","levelPath":"fatal/service-runner/worker","msg":"Unexpected token ...","time":"2018-12-15T21:18:07.898Z","v":0}
Dec 15 21:18:08 server.live-servers.net node[18799]: {"name":"parsoid","hostname":"server.live-servers.net","pid":18799,"level":40,"message":"first worker died during startup, continue startup","worker_pid":18811,"exit_code":1,"startup_attempt":1,"levelPath":"warn/service-runner/master","msg
Dec 15 21:18:09 server.live-servers.net systemd[1]: Started MediaWiki Parsoid Server.
lines 1-15/15 (END)
```

## Looking for the port 8000

```
root@server:/etc/systemd/system# netstat -tulpn | grep 8000
root@server:/etc/systemd/system#
```

## However I can see that the node application is running

```
root@server:/etc/systemd/system# ps ax | grep node
18799 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/node /var/www/gwart/mediawiki/extensions/VisualEditor/parsoid/bin/server.js
20820 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto node
```

## Service file

```
[Unit]
Description=MediaWiki Parsoid Server

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /var/www/gwart/mediawiki/extensions/VisualEditor/parsoid/bin/server.js
Restart=always
User=root
Group=root
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin/node:/usr/local/bin
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/gwart/mediawiki/extensions/VisualEditor/parsoid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I believe it is related to this question:
[Starting node application with `node` works but not when starting it with `/usr/bin/node`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53797565/starting-node-application-with-node-works-but-not-when-starting-it-with-usr)

Comment: So it does not die when you run it with `node`? Then please post the output of `whereis node` as well as `node -v` and `/usr/bin/node -v`.

Comment: Of course!! `v4.2.6` for `/usr/bin/node` but other `6` for `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/node` Let me test this out now :)

Comment: Yep, in that case `ExecStart=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/node [...]` should do the trick. :)

Comment: Ye, although I should really map my default `nvm` version to `/usr/bin/node` incase I ever upgrade it :D Amazing, may as well add that as the answer and I'll accept bud

Comment: Yes, wanted to add that. You should use a symlink as that location does not seem too permanent. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/bin/node` seems to be the node executeable installed by the package manager and too old(`v4.2.6`) for `parsoid`.

The command `node` worked here because that command was linked to `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/bin/node` installed by `nvm` running `v6.7.0`.

To fix this, create a symlink to your current nvm version (in order to able to easily adjust when you update) and use that path in your `.service` file.

**Note:**
I wouldn't recommand deleting the symlink or file `/usr/bin/node` in order to place a symlink with that name there, as that might interfere withe the "stock" node installation.